# Recursive strings or macros substitution

Tags: javascript, macros, substitution, m4

I'm trying to create FizzBuzz using only lambdas in JavaScript based on [Programming With Nothing](http://codon.com/programming-with-nothing) article. I've got it [working with variables](https://github.com/jcubic/FizzBuzz/blob/master/FizzBuzz.js) but now I want to replaces all usage of variables (uppercase strings), I've try to use m4 for this, I've create define for each variable like:

```
define(`ZERO', `p => x => x')
define(`ONE', `p => x => p(x)')
define(`TWO', `p => x => p(p(x))')
define(`THREE', `p => x => p(p(p(x)))')
define(`FIVE', `p => x => p(p(p(p(p(x)))))')
define(`FIFTEEN', `p => x => p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(x)))))))))))))))')
define(`HUNDRED', `p => x => p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(x))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))')
...
module.exports = MAP(RANGE(ONE)(HUNDRED))( n => IF(IS_ZERO(MOD(n)(FIFTEEN)))(
    FIZZBUZZ
)(IF(IS_ZERO(MOD(n)(THREE)))(
    FIZZ
)(IF(IS_ZERO(MOD(n)(FIVE)))(
    BUZZ
)(
    TO_DIGITS(n)
))));
```

and run m4 but it didn't work It didn't substitute recursivly to show onlyu arrow functions, I've got this as output (the article program is much bigger):

```
module.exports = k => f => f => (x => f(p => x(x)(p)))(x => f(p => x(x)(p)))(x => y => f => f(x)(y)(x => y => x))(l => x => l => x => x => y => f => f(x)(y)(x => y => f => f(x)(y)(l))(f(x)))( n => b => b(
    l => x => x => y => f => f(x)(y)(x => y => f => f(x)(y)(l))(n => p => x => p(n(p)(x)))
)(b => b(
    l => x => x => y => f => f(x)(y)(x => y => f => f(x)(y)(l))(n => p => x => p(n(p)(x)))
)(b => b(
    l => x => x => y => f => f(x)(y)(x => y => f => f(x)(y)(l))(m => n => n(m => n => n(n => p => x => p(n(p)(x)))(m))(p => x => x)(p => x => p(p(p(p(p(x)))))))
)(
    f => (x => f(p => x(x)(p)))(x => f(p => x(x)(p)))
))));
```

The `HUNDRED` didn't get replaced there are no `p(` 100 times in the output.

here is [whole m4 program](https://github.com/jcubic/FizzBuzz/blob/master/macros.m4)

Is there a way to have one single expression for the whole program, using m4 or any other tool?

Comment: Like a single recursive macro?  Why don't you do something like (the following pseudo-code: `define N, if N has no args, return string, else if N has 1 arg, return different string, else if N has more than 1 arg, do a recursive loop, adding more and more levels of \`p\` for each level of recursion.`

Comment: Also, consider using `divert(-1)` at the start of your m4 code; followed by `divert(0)` at the end of it, so that all the whitespace around and in between the m4 code doesn't show up in the resultant file when you churn it through `m4`.

Comment: Something like this: `define(\`nth', \`ifelse(\`$1', 0, \`p => x => x', \`$1', 1, \`p => x => p(x)', m4_cmp($1, 2), 1, \`define(\`idx', decr(m4_expand($1)))$0(idx)')')`        `m4_cmp` and `m4_expand` are both part of m4sugar.m4, which are part of autoconf. I've tried directly incorporating m4sugar into m4 code, but it's never worked; just rip those macros from m4sugar and change the quotes as needed